# How does one find the expected value of $\text{E}(XY)$ when $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ is not zero?

Tags: self-study, correlation, expected-value, joint-distribution

What do I need to determine $\text{E}(XY)$ when $\text{Cov}(X,Y) \neq 0$?

Comment: what is the meaning of "expected value of dependent joint distributions"? If you mean $\mathbb{E}[(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]$ when the $X_i$'s are dependent, it is $(\mathbb{E}[X_1],...,\mathbb{E}[X_1])$ and dependence does not play a role in the expectation.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an for your comment. I refer to Theorem 3 in [this simplified proof](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n3/stein.html "http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n3/stein.html") that says if X and Y are statistically independent, then E(XY) = E(X) E(Y). What happens if the covariance of X and Y is not zero, does that mean they are not independent? Is it then possible to determine E(XY)? I have been searching for an answer to this question everywhere and I suspect I am not using the right keywords, so I appreciate any comments you can make to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, they are dependent just using the result you cite and logic.  If $\text{Cov}(X, Y) \neq 0$ then $\text{E}(XY) \neq \text{E}(X) \text{E}(Y)$.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your attempts to get the basics of Probability theory as your question seems to indicate a lack of background on the topic?

Comment: Thanks dsaxton and Xi'an. Yes I have only a basic grasp of probability theory. In geoscience with heterogeneous systems, the parameters that are used to describe the system are assumed to be normally distributed and independent, e.g. fluid flux and reaction rate constants. I have been able to measure the actual spatial distributions now themselves and want to test this assumption.

Comment: If, for simplicity for my sake, we consider a system Z = XY, and I find that E(XY)≠E(X)E(Y). What equations or topics of probability theory should I look into if I want to use the new data I acquired, where I know X and Y everywhere, therefore I should be able to derive stuff like Cov(X,Y) - to calculate E(XY)? In the process I hope to characterise X,Y by some measures like Cov(X,Y) instead of the full dataset.

Comment: The [definition of and formulas for covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition) would be a good start.

Comment: Okay, I have access to Matlab and can use the cov function. How can I now determine E(XY) if I don't assume X and Y are independent or normal? I have found topics on how to predict X if I know Y and the correlation or covariance, but not when I don't assume they are independent and normal.

Comment: It is clear that the OP is confused about the issues at hand, but that's why he is asking the question. I don't see that this is sufficiently unclear that it needs to be closed.

Comment: @gung Personally I would like clarification on whether the OP means $E(XY)$ (which seems to be the matter of discussion in the comments) or (as currently written) $E(X,Y)$. But once that is clarified I'd have no problem with this question remaining open/being reopened if it is closed. I wouldn't even mind this question standing as "what is the notational difference between $E(X,Y)$ and $E(XY)$?" - which seems to be part of the confusion and could be a perfectly good question in its own right! Though I sense the OP is looking for more than this.

Comment: @Silverfish, I agree w/ all of that.

Comment: Ahah! I missed that important subtlety. I mean E(XY) then. If that is a suitable generalisation of the problem Z=AB+CD and I don't want to assume A,B,C,D are normal and independent such that I can use their averages to find E(Z)

Comment: Sorry I missed your message @Pete. If you mean E(XY) I suggest you edit your question, and this question will get put into the "reopen" queue for other people to look at to see if it is sufficiently clarified. If reopened then it's possible for fresh answers to be posted.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwillbucwJveAhXoGDQIHcUzAhYQFjAEegQIMBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.physicsforums.com%2Fthreads%2Fexpectations-on-the-product-of-two-dependent-random-variables.276125%2F&usg=AOvVaw3DYNorxZANgJLkj3cInguI

Answer (score 3):

As Xi'an points out, the joint distribution - the fact that random variables are (possibly) dependent - does not play a role. 
If you know the expected value of each random variable then you are done (e.g. you have known marginals and apply a copula, then the expected values do not change).

If you only have the joint density, then you would need to calculate the marginals:
$$
f_{X_j} (x) = \int \int  f(x_1, \ldots, x, \ldots x_n) d{x_1} \cdots d{x_n}
$$
and then you can calculate the expected value of $X_j$. Doing this analytically or numerically can be difficult ...

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer. Perhaps you could comment on my understanding here.
Theorem 3 from [a simplified proof online](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n3/stein.html "http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n3/stein.html") says that if X and Y are statistically independent, then E(XY) = E(X) E(Y). If covariance of X and Y is not zero, does that mean X and Y are not statistically independent?

Comment: Your reference deals with discrete distributions. In the density case it is true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$ then the expectation $ \int \int xy f_{X,Y}(x,y)  dx dy = \int x f(x) dx \int y f(y) dy $. So yes. If the corrrelation is not zero then they are dependent. But the reverse is not true. If the correlation is zero then ther can be dependence (think of orthogonal random varibles scaled by a common factor).